# QNetworkAccessManager QWaitCondition

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

When I use the QNetworkAccessManager, I always prompt "QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting"

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import *

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    clicked = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)


        self.m_NetManger = QNetworkAccessManager(parent=self)
        self.m_NetManger.finished.connect(self.on_reply)
        self.m_Reply = self.m_NetManger.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://www.google.com")))

    def on_reply(self, reply):
        if self.m_Reply.error() == QNetworkReply.NoError:
            print("ok")
        else:
            print("error")

        self.m_Reply.deleteLater()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MainWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I have tested your code in Linux and I do not have that problem, is that the code that generates that error ?, that error is when you implement the QThreads incorrectly

Comment: The system I use is win10 64 bits.